# VSCode Language Support for Java extesion automatically adds .settings, .project and .classpath to directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a Maven project with Scala and Java. I generally develop it using Intellij IDEA, however, I sometimes open it in Visual Studio Code.

Whenever I do that, it automatically adds .settings directory, .project file and .classpath file to the root of each module in the project.

This is seemed to occur due to the Language Support for Java by Red hat extension.

I would very much like to avoid this, how would I do that?

Comment: `.settings`, `.project` and `.classpath` are files/directories generated by Eclipse, not by VSCode. VSCode creates a directory named `.vscode`.

Comment: They are generated by visual studio code, automatically. I am not sure why, I expected to see .vscode in the root but in practice I see these three in each and every subdirectory whenever I opened it in VSCode. This is the reason for the question.

Comment: VSCode does not generate those files. Maybe one of its extensions you have installed does.

Comment: How do I test which extension does it and how to stop it? BTW I would suspect the language support for java by redhat.

Comment: I would disable all extensions, remove the `.settings`, `.project` and `.classpath` files/directories and restart VSCode. Then I would enable the extensions one by one (and possibly restart VSCode just to be sure) until I find the one that produces the files. The `.classpath` file definitely points to an extension from the Java world so you better start with the Java-related extensions to find it faster.

Comment: I validated that the java language extension is indeed the cause. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Here is the related discussion on this extension's GitHub page: [Any way to get rid of .project .classpath .settings/ files?](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [*Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) (aka vscode-java) extension generate those Eclipse files, because, under the hood, a customized, headless Eclipse process ([jdt.ls](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls)) is providing all the Java support. You can not remove these files, if you expect proper Java support by this VS Code extension.

So your alternatives are:

- add these files to your .gitignore (if you're using git, else, ignore them from whatever SCM you use)
- disable or uninstall vscode-java and use a different Java extension in VS Code